# Android view class - drawing View over button - background vs foreground?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design

I'm drawing an ImageView (a 50% transparent icon) over an ImageButton, but the icon **disappears** when I click the ImageButton (an Activity transition gets triggered at this moment). That looks pretty awful...

What is the best approach to do this, without actually putting the icon into the src-File of the ImageButton? Is there a way to do it with setting drawables as background or foreground? And what exactly are those two properties for? I can't find any documentation about android:foreground...

BTW: I'm using the new Lollipop shared element transition and testing on a nexus 9.

```
<Relative Layout...>
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_width="400dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:src="@drawable/call1"
    android:foreground="@drawable/phone" <!-- Does this make any sense?-->
    android:transitionName="@string/trans_call_pic"
    android:onClick="clickCall"
    />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:src="@drawable/phone"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/imageView1"
    android:alpha="0.5"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    />
</RelativeLayout
```

Answer (score 1):

The `android:foreground` attribute is for a foreground selector (added to a FrameLayout). It's not intended to simply draw an image.

One solution would be to wrap the button & the image in a container view and put your transition on the container. This way the two child views would be treated as one.

Comment: Okay that sounds good. Do you have some resource to read into the topic of foreground?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a foreground selector to your view. You can extend `ImageButton`, override `onDraw()`, and draw the foreground selector *after* calling `super.onDraw()`. This will ensure that the foreground selector is drawn on top of the entire `ImageButton`. More detailed instructions can be found [**here**](http://antoine-merle.com/blog/2013/07/17/adding-a-foreground-selector-to-a-view/).